# asp.net use client validation without posting to server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a very long form that is divided in sections. I want to take advantage of the built-in ASP.NET validation controls without posting back to the server until the form is submitted. To provide more context, let me explain my idea. The form is divided in sections and each section will have a "Next" button. When the "Next" button is clicked, the section is validated with the client-side code that ASP.NET includes. If the section is valid, a jquery method will hide the section and show the next one. When the user reaches the last section of the form, a "Submit" button will be available and this button will fire the event to post the form to the server.

Any help or idea will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: To provide more context you need to provide your code, and till now what u have tried

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you need to do?

Comment: Try considering "Validation Groups" in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

For this you can have n no of Panel and each Panel will have a Next button. For validation each Panel will contain a validation group...so u need to have n no of validation group.

So each Panel will have a validation setup. Now u can have jquery on each button to hide the Panel and move the user to the next Panel.

I hope this can fulfill your requirement.